# jQuery show() on specific drop-down selection

Tags: jquery

When a certain value from a drop-down box is selected, I want another section of the form to be shown using jQuery's show() function. Currently, my code above the header looks like this:

```
<script>   
    $(":input#location").change(function(){
      if($(this).val() === 'On Rental'){
        $('div#dpo').show("slow");
      }
    }
</script>
```

And, the form is coded like this:

```
<p>
    <strong><label for="location">Location</label></strong>
</p>
<select name="location" id="location">
    <option value="Clarksville">Clarksville</option>
    <!--etc.-->
</select>

<div id="dpo" style="display:none">
  <!--Stuff I want to show here.-->
</div>
```

For some reason, nothing happens when I select "On Rental" from the drop-down field, and I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FYI you can just do `$(#dpo)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all of the suggestions above (including wrapping it in the document.ready function), but I couldn't get it to work . I eventually got the code to work (as I originally had it) when I placed at the bottom of the document, rather than in the header. I don't know enough about JavaScript and jQuery to know why that would be...?

Answer (score 1):

trim the value and try as below , another thing is if you are using id than no need to specify tage type in the selector

```
$("#location").change(function(){ 
      if($.trim($(this).val()) == 'On Rental'){
         $('#dpo').show("slow");
       }
     }
```

Comment: Why the need to trim?  It's a hardcoded value inside an option isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>   
$("input#location").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() === 'On Rental'){
    $('div#dpo').show("slow");
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a document.ready function.  Also you can just use `ID` selectors.  And your select isn't an input type..

```
$(function(){
    $("#location").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'On Rental') {
            $('#dpo').show("slow");
        }
    }​
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/FYwPv/